# How do I display a table returned by a JQuery ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am developing in CakePHP.

Here is the ajax:

```
$.ajax
({
     url: 'http://domnain/subdomain/controller/add/',
     accepts: 'text',
     context: document.body,
     type: 'POST',
     data: account_data,
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR )
     {
          .
          .
          .

          $('#account_post_message').html( data );

          .
          .
          .
```

The target controller creates the following:

```
$return_html = '<table><tr><td>American Express</td><td>5678</td><td>10/13</td></tr></table>';
```

which is echoed `echo $return_html;` to the ajax and is places in the "account_post_message" `<div>`.

Unfortunately, the text string appears as a string.

How can I make the table appear as a table?

Comment: @user729855 - welcome. I've edited your post to show the code properly.  You can do it by highlighting the section you want to format as code and then clicking the code button (looks like {}) on the markdown table in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all the returned value is a string, not an HTML markup string; its just text. You can change the return value to be HTML markup or parse the returned string in your JavaScript to produce HTML markup to be added to the "account_post_message"

For example:

```
$return_html = 'table table_row table_data American Express end_table_data table_data 5678 end_table_data table_data 10/13 end_table_data end_table_row end_table';
```

Should be something like:

```
$return_html = '<table><tr><td>American Express</td><td>5678</td><td>10/13</td></tr></table>';
```

Like I said you can make the controller return this HTML or replace the string tokens in your response with the corresponding HTML tags

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can I sent the html without enclosing it in quotes?

Comment: If your controller file is a php file then whatever you expect normally to be handled by the browser will be sent back to the ajax call and into the data variable. So if you would normally echo the $return_html variable to the browser, doing so in the controller file in this instance would send that same 'string' to the ajax success handler. In shorter words: whatever your controller returns is exactly what will be in the data variable.

Comment: How do I return html from the controller?

Comment: Im guessing your controller file does some calculations and fills a variable called $return_html with the necessary output. If you call echo $return_html then this is the output from this file. An ajax call will take that output and store it in the data variable. So in your controller have the string you build be HTML markup instead of what you have in the first line.

Comment: I have previously used the echoed value to display a string message on the browser. Now I want the echoed value to be an html table which looks like a table on the browser. How do I send a value that will be interpreted as a table by the browser?

Comment: I see now what you mean, there may be a couple issues you need to check. 1) Ensure that $('#account_post_message') is actually getting the right element, 2) Ensure that data is holding the right value (ie send it in an alert window or something. Give us that output in your original post and lets go from there

Comment: This is the element  <div style="padding-left: 20px;" id="account_post_message"></div>. It has been receiving a message that the data was successfully posted. Now it shows "<table><tr><td>American Express</td><td>5678</td><td>10/13</td></tr></table>". btw, this <div> is not the ultimate destination of the table. I am using it for testing purposes because I know that I can put the ajax returned text into it and it is displayed correctly.

Comment: You are not going to believe this. It started working. I didn't make any change to the code as I presented it, I worked on something unrelated. Now it works. Thanks for your help.